# PHP-Driver DataStax Cassandra DB - How to use?

Tags: nginx, cassandra, debian, php-7, nosql

I've done the installation process as following:

System

> PHP 7.0.5-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS )
>
> Debian 8
>
> Nginx 1.8.1
>
> Laravel 5.2

Java Installation

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
wget URL to Oraclesite
mv mv jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz\?... jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar xzf jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz
rm jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_version/bin/java" 1
update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_version/bin/java
```

Install needed packages

```
apt install cmake automake libtool git php7.0-dev libgmp-dev libssl-dev
```

Libuv Installation

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.7.5/libuv-v1.7.5.tar.gz
tar xzf libuv-v1.7.5.tar.gz
rm libuv-v1.9.0.tar.gz
cd libuv-v1.7.5
sh autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
ldconfig
```

Installation Cassandra Datatrax

```
echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
curl -L http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -
apt install cassandra dsc30
```

Check services

```
service cassandra status
```

> cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured
>   data    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra)    Active: active
>   (running) since Mon 2016-04-11 01:11:04 CEST; 19min ago   Process: 506
>   ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
>   CGroup: /system.slice/cassandra.service

```
nodetool status
```

> Datacenter: datacenter1
>   ======================= Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>   --  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack UN  127.0.0.1  139.06 KB  256          100.0%
>   1ab0e99a-41a5-4007-b9ca-de58dc88e318  rack1

```
cqlsh
```

> Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042. [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra
>   3.0.4 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4] 
>   Use HELP for help.

Installation php-driver 
(PECL Installation isn't working. I think it's because of only php7 setup)

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
cd php-driver
git submodule update --init
cd ext
./install.sh
make test -> all tests passed
```

Add Driver to PHP Extensions

```
echo -e "; DataStax PHP Driver\nextension=cassandra.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

// UPDATE - added extension to fpm/php.ini file.
echo -e "; DataStax PHP Driver\nextension=cassandra.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

Restart nginx and php7.0-fpm

```
service nginx restart
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

**Question:**

If I wanna use the following code it says me class Cassandra not found.
Webpage: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver#datastax-php-driver-for-apache-cassandra

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()->build();
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to execute your PHP script using nginx+fpm you will need to update the appropriate php.ini file (e.g. `/etc/php7/fpm/php.ini`).

Add the driver module to your nginx+fpm installation

```
echo -e "; DataStax PHP Driver\nextension=cassandra.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

To ensure the the driver is being properly loaded via CLI you can execute the following:

```
php -m | grep cassandra
```

or

```
php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"
```

`php -m` will print out all the extension/modules that PHP was able to load whereas `php -i` will display more verbose information about your PHP installation configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 1**

When I execute the following 2 commands I get the following two results, which looks quite successful.

***php -m | grep cassandra***

> cassandra

***php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"***

> cassandra
>
> Cassandra support => enabled C/C++ driver version => 2.2.2 Persistent
> Clusters => 0 Persistent Sessions => 0
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value cassandra.log =>
> cassandra.log => cassandra.log cassandra.log_level => ERROR => ERROR

But still the error no class Cassandra.

**UPDATE 2**

Everything working now.

```
php > $cluster = Cassandra::cluster()->build(); 
php > var_dump($cluster); 
object(Cassandra\DefaultCluster)#2 (0) { } 
php >
```